# Check if element is in-build or custom element

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering if there is a way to check if an element is in-built or custom element.

I know one option using `element.constructor.name`, to check if its not [HTMLUnknownElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLUnknownElement). But the question is, how does the engine determines if element is unknown element or known element.

Following is a sample:

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.content > *');
Array.from(elements).forEach(el => {
  console.log(el.constructor.name)
})
```

```html
<div class='content'>
  <test-element>Test Element</test-element>
  <testElement>Dummy</testElement>
</div>
```

If you notice, adding hyphens(`-`) makes engine to process it as a known element.

So is there a concrete way to determine if the element is unknown element?

Comment: whats your definition of an "in-built" element?

Comment: Which HTML specification [there are several](https://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html)

Comment: Make a big array of "built-in" element node names and compare.

Comment: @Liam Any tag that is registered with DOM. In simple, how does compiler know what element is *unknown element*? We have a lot of pre-defined tags like `h`, `i`, `div etc etc. We can also have custom components. But there must be a way to define which is which. People have spend so much effort in defining semantics making `h1-h6`, `header`, `footer` sections. So I'm assuming there must be a way for this as well

Comment: compiler? There is no compiler in Js or HTML? Do you mean a rendering engine? Because they will implement different rules depending on the browser(though this is less of an issue these days than it used to be)/DTD selected.

Comment: Yes engine. apologies for incorrect term

Comment: @Liam I think you mean "parser", not rendering engine, which is different.

Comment: @James That is one possible way. But would require a lot of maintenance. Lets try to see if someone has a better approach.

Comment: @Liam Ah, come on Liam. Don't be so petty. You know exactly what he means.

Comment: So `<applet>` is that valid or not @StanE?

Comment: @Liam The question was how to find this out with JavaScript. The used HTML specification (no matter which one is used) / the engine should know it for itself. (if I understood the questioner correctly).

Comment: *the engine should know it for itself* what engine @StanE? The Javascript engine? Because Javascript doesn't know the DTD (or care). This is the point. The OP hasn't specified what the definition of an "in-built" element is and there are multiple standards. Without a clear definition of what exactly is required here how can this be answered? HTML is just a subset of XML. XML can only be defined as "valid" against a DTD. So my "petty" questions are simply trying to define what exactly is required here as it is not as straight forward as the OP thinks.

Comment: @Liam You are right. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about a fool-proof way (maybe invoke a DOM Parser?), but if you could determine the naming conventions that cause problems getting accurate results, you could use a regular expression to filter the characters causing the issue out, create a "dummy" element from the corrected `nodeName` and then test the dummy:

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.content > *');
Array.from(elements).forEach(el => {
  var dummy = document.createElement(el.nodeName.replace(/-+/, ""));
  console.log(dummy.constructor.name)
})
```

```html
<div class='content'>
  <test-element>Test Element</test-element>
  <testElement>Dummy</testElement>
</div>
```

You could also take the element and make it part of an XHTML dummy document and then validate that document using an XML Parser against the XHTML schema/DTD, but I don't believe there is a standard one for XHTML5. Anyway, here's some code that will at least convert your test HTML strings into XHTML syntax. The next step would be to programatically validate it.

```js
const parser = new DOMParser();


var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.content > *');

Array.from(elements).forEach(el => {

  var doc = parser.parseFromString(el.outerHTML, "text/html");
  var result = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(doc);  

  console.log(result);
})
```

```html
<div class='content'>
  <test-element>Test Element</test-element>
  <testElement>Dummy</testElement>
</div>
```

I also found this HTML Tag Validator as a **[Node Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-tag-validator)**

Comment: My objective is to know if there is a concrete way. This is just one of case. I'm more interested in knowing why `test-element` is processed as HTMLElement?

Comment: @Rajesh As mentioned in my answer, I believe using a DOM Parser or validating as XHTML would do it.

Comment: XHTML parsing sounds interesting. Will check.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`customElements.get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/get) to check if an element has been registered as a custom element. For example

```js
/** @param {HTMLElement} element */
function isCustomElement(element) {
  const tagName = element.tagName.toLowerCase()
  return Boolean(customElements.get(tagName))
}
```

Usage

```js
for (const el of document.querySelectorAll('.content > *')) {
  console.log(el.tagName, isCustomElement(el))
}
```